# UserManager.CreateAsync() requires a complex password

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm designing a register form and using ajax to send data to server.

My model:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

and the action:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)    
   {
      var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

      var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

      if (result.Succeeded)
      {
         // do stuff...
      }
   }
}
```

My problem: `result.Succeeded` returned `false` with error message (`Password` is `helloworld`):

> Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character.
>   Passwords must have at least one digit ('0'-'9'). Passwords must have
>   at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z').

As you can see above, I didn't set any regular expression to `Password` and `ConfirmPassword`. So why was I getting that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using Identity. In the IdentityConfig.cs, there's a section where you configure the requirements for password. Look for this section:

```
   manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
```